# Second promise is not working properly

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise

I have the following `promise` that works perfectly:

```
self.getAll = function (callback) {
    var users= [];
    var promises = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: "/API/Users",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (results) {
            var mappedContacts = $.map(results, function (item) {
                promises.push($.ajax({
                    url: "/API/Users/contacts/" + item.id,
                    type: "GET"
                }).then(function (contacts) {
                    users.push(new User(item, contacts));
                }));
            });
            $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
                callback(users);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I'm trying to add a second `AJAX` request but it's not working properly:

```
self.getAll = function (callback) {
    var users= [];
    var promises = [];
    $.ajax({
        url: "/API/Users",
        type: "GET",
        success: function (results) {
            var mappedContacts = $.map(results, function (item) {
                promises.push($.ajax({
                    url: "/API/Users/contacts/" + item.id,
                    type: "GET"
                }).then(function (contacts) {
                    users.push(new User(item, contacts));
                }));
            });
            var mappedContacts2 = $.map(results, function (item) {
                promises.push($.ajax({
                    url: "/API/Users/contacts2/" + item.id,
                    type: "GET"
                }).then(function (contacts2) {
                    users.push(new User(item, "",contacts2));
                }));
            });
            $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
                callback(users);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

`contacts2` is always empty, what am I doing wrong?

This is the `User` object:

```
var User= function (data, contacts, contacts2) {
    this.id = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.contacts = ko.observableArray(contacts);
    this.contacts2 = ko.observableArray(contacts2 );
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "empty"? Why is empty string passed at second parameter to `new User(item, "",contacts2)` at `.then()` at `mappedContacts2`, though not at `mappedContacts` `new User(item, contacts)`? Does `User()` call expect two parameters or three parameters?

Comment: Please see my edited question. When I `console.log` the `users` before `callback(users);` it is not empty but when I try to access it in the page `contatcs2` is always `[]`

Comment: The parameters passed to each respective `User()` call at `.then()` chained to `$.ajax()` calls are different. `User` function appears to expect three parameters. Only two parameters are passed at first call to `User()`; three parameters are passed at second call to `User()`. That is the only difference between code within `$.map()` calls that am able to determine at `javascript` at Question.

Comment: What does `/API/Users?UserId=1` return? User objects? How many? Also, why is it not a RESTful URL? And why is UserId=1 hard-coded?

Comment: I'm not really sure how to do it, the `User` object expects 3 parameters but the second and the third one are being obtained from 2 different functions...

Comment: _"but the second and the third one are being obtained from 2 different functions"_ ? An empty string is passed at second parameter at second `User()` call, not the result of a function call. No third parameter is passed at first call to `User()`. If _"I have the following promise that works perfectly:"_ is accurate, then the same should be true if you duplicate the process for `mappedContacts2`

Comment: @Tomalak `/API/Users` return an aray of `id` and `name`, based on the id of each `User` I get an array: `contacts` and an array: `contacts2`. the `UserId=1` is not relevant and not being used, I removed it.

Comment: @user3378165 How would you get `contacts2` at first call to `User()` where third parameter is not passed to `var User= function (data, contacts, contacts2) {}` at `users.push(new User(item, contacts));`? `contacts2` would be `undefined` at  `this.contacts2 = ko.observableArray(contacts2 );`

Comment: You need a `$.when` also for each user....and create user after promises for `contacts1 ` and `contacts2` resolve

Comment: Note also, no value is actually returned from either `$.map()` or `.then()`. It is not clear what expected result is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need both sets of contacts for each user to pass to `new User()` use one `map()` that returns a `$.when()` for both contacts requests. Create the user in `then()` of that `$.when()`

Something like:

```
self.getAll = function(callback) {
  var users = [];
  // return this promise ..... see notes below
  return $.getJSON("/API/Users").then(results) {

    // map array of promises to pass to final $.when
    var promises = $.map(results, function(item) {

      var req1 = $.getJSON("/API/Users/contacts/" + item.id);
      var req2 = $.getJSON("/API/Users/contacts2/" + item.id);

      // return this promise to mapped array
      return $.when(req1, req2).then(function(contacts1, contacts2) {
        // create user now that we have both sets of contacts
        users.push(new User(item, contacts1, contacts2));
      });
    })

    // should return this promise .... see notes below
    return $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
      callback(users);
      // return `users` ...see notes below
    });

  })
}
```

Using a callback is an outdated approach when you could just return the promise chain shown in comments above and do :

```
self.getAll().then(function(users) {
  // do something with users
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, very well explained, I just had to make a few fixes in order to get it to work: the `function` was missing here: `then(function (results)`, and also- `$.when` assign an array of values to the `done callback` for ajax values that is `[data, status, jqxhr]`, so we just need to put first item of the array instead of the array itself, so I changed `users.push(new User(item, contacts1, contacts2));` to `users.push(new User(item, contacts1[0], contacts2[0]));` Thank you very much for your help!